# Strange problem with conversion

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

In code below:

```
template<class Key, class Value>
    class Pair
    {
    private:
        std::pair<Key,Value> body_;
    public:
        //No cpy ctor - this generated by compiler is OK
        Pair(Key&& key,Value&& value)
        {
            body_.first = key;
            body_.second = value;
        }

        Pair(Pair<Key,Value>&& tmpPattern)
        {
            body_.swap(tmpPattern.body_);
        }

        Pair& operator=(Pair<Key,Value> tmpPattern)
        {
            body_.swap(tmpPattern.body_);
            return *this;
        }

                };

    template<class Key, class Value>
    Pair<Key,Value> MakePair(Key&& key, Value&& value)
    {
        return Pair<Key,Value>(key,value);
    }
```

For some bizzare reason I'm getting error when I try to run MakePair, why? God knows...

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
auto tmp = MakePair(1, 2);
}
```

This is this error:
**Error error C2665: Pair::Pair' : none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types**

I just don't understand what conversion there is to be performed?

Comment: With `&&`, isn't it required that the function parameters are references?

Comment: @Victor, no `&&` can take rvalues

Comment: Anyway, this compiles fine for me on GCC 4.3.2.  However, since there is not yet support for `auto`, I had to replace it with `Pair<int,int> tmp = MakePair(1, 2)`.  Could it be your compiler simply has somewhat buggy C++0x support?

Comment: @Charles It's very possible. I'm using VS2010 Ultimate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return Pair<Key,Value>(std::forward<Key>(key),std::forward<Value>(value));`

Although I'm not really sure why rvalue forwarding isn't implicit.

Edit: Oh, I guess I got it. This way you can still pass a rvalue reference to a function that takes value.

Comment: thanks it works but now I've encountered a problem that when I want to pass variables instead of constants I'm getting another error. Any idea why?

Comment: @There Well, in that case you should use `std::move`. Lvalues can't implicitly decay into rvalues, that would be pretty crazy (loosing ownership by passing a variable into a function) :-D

Comment: you mean std::move instead of std::forward?

Comment: @There No, I mean like this: `int x = 10; auto tmp = MakePair(std::move(x),20);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass values to `MakePair`, not types. Try this:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
auto tmp = MakePair( a, b ); // creates a Pair<int,int> with the values of a and b
```

Comment: still no go (different error) but if I pass instead of MakePair(a,b) this MakePair(1,2) I'm getting same error as previously.